# Can't reach RMI server/RMI registry

Tags: java, linux, rmi

I've started rmiregistry on both machines, i've been able to successfully bind the rmiserver, and it keeps running in the thread, without any exception. However when i run a method through the rmi client from linux terminal from an other machine, im getting exception (when getting the rmiregistry) that the host can't be reached. host being the address where the rmiserver is running (and is bound)

this is my rmiserver code

```
    public class MQAgentServer implements MQAgent, Runnable {    
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        getProperties();
        System.setProperty("java.security.Policy", "java.security.AllPermission");
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", hostName);

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "RCMQAgent";
            MQAgent engine = new MQAgentServer();
            MQAgent stub = (MQAgent) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("MQAgentServer bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("MQAgentServer exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }
```

and here is the rmi client code

```
public class MQAgentClient {

    protected static MQAgent netConn = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }


        String resourceType = args[0];
        String resourceName = args[1];
        String action = args[2];
        String hostName = args[3];

        System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND:INSIDE MQAgentClient.java");

        try {
            if (hostName != null && !hostName.trim().equals("")) {
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostName);
                netConn = (MQAgent) registry.lookup(MQAgent.LOOKUPNAME);
            }

            File file = new File("/home/mpadmin/log/ClientLog.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(resourceType + resourceName + action + hostName);

            if ((resourceType != null && !resourceType.trim().equals("")) && (resourceName != null && !resourceName.trim().equals("")) && (action != null && !action.trim().equals(""))) {

                if (resourceType.trim().equals("QueueManager")) {
                    if (action.trim().equals("Start")) {
                        netConn.startQMGR(resourceName);
                    } else if (action.trim().equals("Stop")) {
                        netConn.stopQMGR(resourceName);
                    } else {
                        writer.write("Illegal Arguments");
                    }
                } else if (resourceType.trim().equals("Process")) {
                    if (action.trim().equals("Start")) {
                        netConn.startProcess(resourceName);
                    } else if (action.trim().equals("Stop")) {
                        netConn.stopProcess(resourceName);
                    } else {
                        writer.write("Illegal Arguments");
                    }
                } else if (resourceType.trim().equals("Channel")) {
                    if (action.trim().equals("Start")) {
                        netConn.startChannel(resourceName);
                    } else if (action.trim().equals("Stop")) {
                        netConn.stopChannel(resourceName);
                    } else {
                        writer.write("Illegal Arguments");
                    }
                }else if (resourceType.trim().equals("Configuration")) {
                    if (action.trim().equals("Fetch")) {
                        netConn.fetchConfiguration(resourceName);
                    }else {
                        writer.write("Illegal Arguments");
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND : REMOTE EXCEPTION when getting rmiregistry\n============================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND : IO EXCEPTION when creating log file\n=======================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND : NotBoundException EXCEPTION when looking up RMIServer in through registry\n=======================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND : GENERIC EXCEPTION inside MQAgent.java\n=======================");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("EXECUTING COMMAND : Command sent to RMI Server successfully");
    }

}
```

this is the command that im using to run the client

```
java -Djava.security.policy=file:/home/<user>/MQAgentClient/client.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/home/<user>/MQAgentClient/bin/ -cp /home/<user>/MQAgentClient/bin;/home/<user>/interface/mqagentinterface.jar com.rc.mqagent.client.MQAgentClient Configuration node0 Fetch <HOST IP WHERE RMISERVER IS RUNNING>
```

I might be missing something obvious, or i might not be providing enough information, just help me resolve this and go easy on me, thanks!

oh and here's the exception in response to the command

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <IP WHERE RMI SERVER IS RUNNING>; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.rc.mqagent.client.MQAgentClient.main(MQAgentClient.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 5 more
```

EDIT:

netstat -tulpn

```
tcp        0      0 :::2426                     :::*                        LISTEN      2283/runmqlsr
tcp        0      0 :::5666                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::1099                     :::*                        LISTEN      1490/./rmiregistry
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:963               0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: no host running this ip `10.206.1.28`.

Comment: i was supposed to mask that. you wont be able to reach that without a vpn network. It's reachable from the machine from where im running the client

Comment: You don't need to start the Registry in the client host. Can you ping that server IP address from the client?

Comment: Oh, but that can't be the problem, right? and Yea the ping is responding fine

Comment: Can you telnet from the client to port 1099 on the server host? This is a network connectivity problem, not an RMI problem.

Comment: you probably have a firewall running. Try switching off [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/) or [firewalld](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-stop-and-disable-firewalld-on-centos-7/)

Comment: I dont have telnet, but i used netstat and posted the response in edit. its being used by rmiregistry

Comment: I guess its the firewall? I don't have root access, will get it checked